# String encoding error in arguments passed to Process.Start

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, arguments

I'm using [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) to concatenate PDF files.

It is done by this code:

```
Private Shared Sub ConcatenateWithCpdf(
                                      outputFileName As String,
                                      inputfilenames() As String,
                                      Optional timeout As Integer = 15000,
                                      Optional ByRef process_exitcode As Integer = 0,
                                      Optional ByRef process_output As String = Nothing,
                                      Optional ByRef process_erroroutput As String = Nothing)
    Dim output As New Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim erroroutput As New Text.StringBuilder()
    Using process As New Process()
        process.StartInfo.FileName = CpdfPath()
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(
            "{0} -o ""{1}""",
            Join(
                inputfilenames.Select(
                    Function(s) String.Format("""{0}""", s)).ToArray,
                " "),
            outputFileName)
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Using outputWaitHandle As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)
            Using errorWaitHandle As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)
                AddHandler process.OutputDataReceived,
                    Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
                        If e.Data Is Nothing Then
                            outputWaitHandle.Set()
                        Else
                            output.AppendLine(e.Data)
                        End If
                    End Sub
                AddHandler process.ErrorDataReceived,
                    Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
                        If e.Data Is Nothing Then
                            errorWaitHandle.Set()
                        Else
                            erroroutput.AppendLine(e.Data)
                        End If
                    End Sub
                process.Start()
                process.BeginOutputReadLine()
                process.BeginErrorReadLine()
                If process.WaitForExit(timeout) AndAlso
                    outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout) AndAlso
                    errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout) Then
                    process_exitcode = process.ExitCode
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    process_output = output.ToString
    process_erroroutput = erroroutput.ToString
End Sub
```

My problem is, some input filenames have non-ASCII characters, like this:

`C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\Procuração - Processo 5001092-92.2017.4.03.6114.pdf`

In this case, CPDF fails and returns this standard output error text:

> cpdf encountered an error. Technical details follow:
>
> C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\Procurac¸a~o - Processo 5001092-92.2017.4.03.6114.pdf: No such file or directory

Obviously, filename was corrupted by some sort of encoding mismatch when passing arguments.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where and how are you getting/generating your list of input file names?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, they are a list of e-mail attachments, they come with their original names. But they are already saved in disk at the point I get the error, so I'm sure their names are valid for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to check file using the following code:

process.StartInfo.FileName = CpdfPath().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)

Look which NormalizationForm could be best for you:

**FormC**

Indicates that a Unicode string is normalized using full canonical decomposition, followed by the replacement of sequences with their primary composites, if possible.

**FormD**

Indicates that a Unicode string is normalized using full canonical decomposition.

**FormKC**

Indicates that a Unicode string is normalized using full compatibility decomposition, followed by the replacement of sequences with their primary composites, if possible.

**FormKD**

Indicates that a Unicode string is normalized using full compatibility decomposition.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the four options above solved the problem. Most peculiar, however, when I used *FormC* or *FormKC*, cpdf error message presented the filename exactly identical to that present in disk, which baffles me completely.

Comment: Hey, now I did it! I combined your answer with the insight from @Idle_Mind above. I applied the `.Normalize` conversion to the filenames **before** saving the component files to disk. So every filename is now normalized. Therefore, I'm going to accept your post as the answer. Phew, I didn't even knew that a strings could be different having identical text in it...